# Where to send authentication data in Axios PUT request

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, axios

I am trying to use an API to generate an AuthKey for a backend coding challenge. The API docs are linked here:

https://api-core-dev.caronsale.de/swagger/#/Authentication/UserAuthenticationAuthenticateUser

When I enter the correct credentials on the API codepen, I get a 201 response and it generates an AuthKey in the response object.

I want to replicate this behaviour using Axios, but I am only getting 401 errors. I have tried including the credentials like this:

```
const apiCall = async () => {
    await axios({
        method: "put",
        url: "https://api-core-dev.caronsale.de/api/v1/authentication/salesman%40random.com",

        data: {
            userMailId: "correctemail@email.com",
            authenticationRequest: {
                password: "password",
                meta: "string",
            },
        },
    })
        .then(() => console.log("done with put request"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

As this best represents the structure seen in the docs, but I'm still getting the same response.

I've been at this for two hours and I'm completely stumped. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the last segment of the URL should be the value of `userMailId` and the data body should be just

```
{
  "password": "string",
  "meta": "string"
}
```

as indicated in the Swagger UI:

[image: portion of swagger ui]

So:

```
const userMailId = "theusermailid@somewhere.com"; // <- change this
await axios({
    method: "put",
    url: `https://api-core-dev.caronsale.de/api/v1/authentication/${encodeURIComponent(userMailId)}`,

    data: {
        password: "password",
        meta: "string",
    },
    // ...
```